# Looping over and combining Swift array of structs?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm trying to create an array of structs (User structs below) where, if the user.name does not yet exist in the array, it appends the user -- but if the user.name is already present ("Mcdonalds" in the below example), then it will simply add the item.amount to the existing struct.
In other words, the below code should create an array of 4 Users, with the User Mcdonalds item.amount totaling 23.44 + 12.33.
I remember doing this sort of thing in JS no sweat, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this in Swift. Thanks for any help!

```
struct User {
    var name: String
    var amount: Double
}

var user1 = User(name: "Mcdonalds", amount: 23.44)
var user2 = User(name: "Wendys", amount: 15.44)
var user3 = User(name: "Cabanos", amount: 12.22)
var user4 = User(name: "Shell Gas", amount: 23.33)
var user5 = User(name: "Mcdonalds", amount: 12.33)
```

Answer (score 2):

To loop over the users they'll need to be in an array to start.

Then you can use `.reduce(into:)` to **reduce them** into one condensed dictionary (the dictionary will allow you to have a unique key (the name of the user here) so that you don't have duplicate entries). Then you can use `.map()` to just get the value and not the key of that dictionary so that the final result will be an array of users.

```
struct User {
    var name: String
    var amount: Double
}

var users = [
    User(name: "Mcdonalds", amount: 23.44),
    User(name: "Wendys", amount: 15.44),
    User(name: "Cabanos", amount: 12.22),
    User(name: "Shell Gas", amount: 23.33),
    User(name: "Mcdonalds", amount: 12.33)
]

var reducedUsers = users.reduce(into: [String: User]()) { (result, nextUser) in
    if let existing = result[nextUser.name] {
        result[nextUser.name] = User(name: nextUser.name, amount: existing.amount + nextUser.amount)
    } else {
        result[nextUser.name] = nextUser
    }
}.map { $0.value }
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean and swifty way is to write an extension for `Array`. Swift is highly protocol-oriented, which means you are able to extend any existing system or self-written class with new functions.

This is just a simple implementation, which uses a function to append or update any given user object:

```
extension Array where Element == User {
    
    /// Appends a not existing user to the array or updates the amount value if user is already present
    mutating func appendOrUpdate(_ userObject: Element) {
        
        // Check if user is already in the array
        if let index = self.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == userObject.name }) {
            
            // Update the amount
            self[index].amount += userObject.amount
            
        }
        else {
            
            // Append the user
            self.append(userObject)
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

As the `where` clause specifies the extension the `Element` of the array only to be applied when the given object is your `User` struct, it is only available when you pass in an user object.

Usage:

```
var userArray: [User] = []
userArray.appenOrUpdate(User(name: "Mcdonalds", amount: 23.44))
userArray.appenOrUpdate(User(name: "Wendys", amount: 15.44))
userArray.appenOrUpdate(User(name: "Cabanos", amount: 12.22))
userArray.appenOrUpdate(User(name: "Shell Gas", amount: 23.33))
userArray.appenOrUpdate(User(name: "Mcdonalds", amount: 12.33))
```

This will result in an array with just four entries and the double entry 'Mcdonalds' user's amount cumulated.

Note that the function has the `mutating` keyword in front, as if not you will not be able to modify the array and its entries. This is necessary due the nature of arrays being Structs themselves.

You can also write a function like the know Array's `append(contentsOf:)` and pass in an array of user objects and loop through them updating or appending the given objects.

Best way is to put this extension in a separate file called `Array+User.swift` according to best practise naming conventions.

You can read more about extensions in Swift and their power here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Comment: This is a nice "swifty" solution, but note that `firstIndex()` has `O(n)` performance, meaning that adding objects to such an array using your `appendOrUpdate()` function will have roughly `O(n²)` performance, which gets **very** slow with all but small numbers of elements. The other solution (By matthew Gray) that uses reduce will be much faster for large arrays.

Comment: I don't think it's appropraite to extend array for something *so* business-logic-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Gray's answer is very good, and can be used for a wide variety of problems that may be more complex than this one. But for this specific problem, it can be done much more simply.

```
let reducedUsers = users.reduce(into: [:]) { (result, user) in
    result[user.name, default: 0] += user.amount
}
.map(User.init)
```

The point of this is that it tears apart the struct into key and value in a Dictionary, and then reassembles the values into an Array at the end. Swift is smart enough to figure out the type of the `[:]`, so there's no need to specify that.

Note that there is a time-space tradeoff here. This creates a temporary Dictionary that can be very large. If this kind of operation is common and the dataset is large, you should consider storing this data in a Dictionary (`[String: User]` or `[String: Double]`) all the time rather than converting back and forth.